# Is SQL injection possible when using MS Access linked tables to a SQL server back-end

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-injection

I've been doing some research on this but so far have pulled a blank. So here's the situation.

I am developing an MS Access front-end that is linking to SQL Server back end.

I am, in part, using linked tables/forms in Access to the SQL DB - such that when the user updates a value in the form, Access automatically (with no code on my part) updates the values in the SQL DB.

So my question is this - is this vulnerable to SQL injection in any way? Or will Access 'parameterize' the update in such a way that any possible SQL injection code will simply be added to the DB 'as is', rather than be parsed on the server and potentially running some malicious code.

Thanks in advance for any pointers on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the classic sense of adding code, commands or additional SQL code that will run on the server the answer is no in regards to standard injection when using linked tables. This is because any T-SQL code on the client side is not passed though the ACE database engine and multiple commands (say separated by a ;) are not passed to the server side. 
However there are some “possible” injections that can occur in an access application, and the SAME applies to linked tables. In other words the introduction of a SQL server into this mix, or using the built in database engine is not subject to classical injection.

So context here is VERY important. As a result, the real question are access applications subject to SQL injection? If one finds a proof of working example that works with the built in ACE engine, then that same injection will exist if you using linked tables to SQL server.

There is no working proof of concept of a SQL injection that will run server side T-SQL code that is possible, or I am aware of being possible.

However if VBA code is using pass-through queries, then the answer is most certainly yes because the Access client would be passing raw t-sql to the server side and not touching such t-sql commands and t-sql statements. So a form that prompts for some parameter value and then is concatenated in VBA to some raw t-sql statement and then sent to SQL server would MOST certainly be subject to SQL injection.

So linked tables, bound forms to those linked tables are not subject to server side injections.

There are some possible cases where an expression pulled from a forms text box used as a parameter in Access sql could modify the intent of a developer.

Eg:

strSQL = "select * from tblCustomers where InvoiceID = " me.TextBoxPrompt

In the above it is expected that the user types in 234324 (a invoice number). However, the user could type in a known VBA function. Depending on the sandbox mode settings you have, then an expression could be entered that is not expected. This could in fact thus cause some VBA to run. (the user would have to be aware of the public VBA function to run).

So in the above, it would not really be sql injection, but VBA injection (a bit of semantics here, but the distinction is important).

So some limited forms of sql injection can occur client side, but such expression will NEVER make it to the server.

At the end of the day this means that by adopting SQL server you do NOT increase in any way the possibility of SQL injection over that of the standard Access product (of which I pointed out some limited types of injection can occur).

The only exception to this rule is if the Access application makes use of pass-through queries that are sent raw to SQL server and user parameters are taken in raw format from the form and passed directly to SQL server. Because I often use pass-through queries that are the result of strings and user prompts then this is an issue. And I often use strings and NOT true ADO parameters (too much work). To prevent injection then I have a small function that removes the “;”, and also () characters from that given string. This small routine thus prevents additional commands being sent to SQL server separated by a “;” for example.

Comment: Thanks Albert, very thorough (as always)!

Answer (score 1):

Using bound forms and not running manually constructed queries:

> is this vulnerable to SQL injection in any way?

No.

> Or will Access 'parameterize' the update in such a way that any possible SQL injection code will simply be added to the DB 'as is'

Yes.

---

From https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/sql-injection-characters-cleaning-function.4021211/#post-14022015 by David Fenton:

> 2. SQL injection is most relevant for applications that do all their
>      editing with SQL. While that would apply to a website backed by a
>      Jet/ACE database (see #1), it doesn't apply to a standard Access
>      app, which doesn't use SQL to edit bound data. That is, most of the
>      data editing in an Access application is via bound forms rather than
>      through SQL, so it's not really going to be susceptible to SQL
>      injection.

Edit:

You can use [Logging ODBC, SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732985/logging-odbc-sql-server) to see how exactly Access interacts with SQL Server via ODBC.

Comment: Thanks for the link Andre. As this link is a forum comment rather than any official documentation, would still be keen to see if anyone knows anything 'official' as to how Access goes about doing its business of transferring data between it and the server when it uses bound forms.

Comment: See edit, and: process of elimination - if SQL injection via Access bound form would be any issue at all, it would be easy to find, and nobody would use Access as frontend anymore.